# The listener in the fragment is always null

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, listener

I have a project with an interface, a main activity and a fragment. Here is the interface:

```
    interface OnClickInterface {
fun onClick(proceed: Boolean)
```

}

Here is the fragment. It has one button:

```
    class FragmentMain() : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding
var listener: OnClickInterface? = null
lateinit var btn: Button

fun initOnClickInterface(listener: OnClickInterface) {
    this.listener = listener
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    btn = binding.button
    btn.setOnClickListener()
    {

        if (listener == null)Toast.makeText(activity, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        listener?.onClick(true) // Trigger the call back
    }

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    return binding.root
}



companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() = FragmentMain().apply { }

}
```

}

My problem is that callback listener is allways null. How can I initialize the listener? Thanks

Comment: Out of the question .. But do not use a setter for listener in fragment .. This can lead to problem when fragment is restored at some point of time .. You can use `FragmentResultAPI` or `ActivityResultAPI` to send back the data .. If that does not works for u or you need a better context for solution edit your question with the actual problem you are trying to solve with listener .

Comment: Depending on how you are using this listener, you may be able to use a shared activity ViewModel instead of a listener. When the button in the fragment is clicked, it notifies the ViewModel and things that need to react to that event can observe the appropriate state in the ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks! It's something to keep in mind!